# Add original message id to headers in a postfix bounce

Tags: postfix

I'm running an [OSticket](https://osticket.com/) support system that utilizes the [Mailcow](https://mailcow.email/) stack for email messaging.

Everything is working fine, except for cases when we cannot email a ticket author due to mailbox issues on their end etc.

In these cases what happens is:

1. OS Ticket tries to send an email by conventional means via Mailcow's stack
2. The email fails to send and Postfix returns a bounce/"Undeliverable Mail Returned to Sender" email
3. OS Ticket acts as though a new ticket has been created by the Mailer Daemon which often gets lost
4. Our support team are not aware that the email has failed to send
5. Our customer never receives help.

Looking into this on the OSTicket end, it seems that OSticket [will try to match the bounce back to the original ticket.](https://forum.osticket.com/d/104433-undelivered-mail-returned-to-sender-processing). However my default configuration of the email side of things does not include the required [headers that OSticket expects](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/blob/4689926b2d3d25754f0ddcf8d4e181a2817f6d56/include/class.mailparse.php#L799).

I'd like to fix this and it seems that adding additional headers may help OSTicket Realize that it is a bounce.

I'm very new to postfix so I'm not sure how to do this, but I'm pretty sure it is doable.

Could anyone help me figure out how to get this configured? Thank you!

I've included the full raw source of one of my bounce emails, it is heavily redacted but perhaps the headers will help.

```
Return-Path: <>
Delivered-To: [REDACTED]
Received: from [REDACTED] ([[REDACTED]])
    by 847cc1941aed with LMTP
    id wPAfFiLbwmWYrwYAydh85g
    (envelope-from <>)
    for <[REDACTED]>; Wed, 07 Feb 2024 01:21:38 +0000
Received: by [REDACTED] (Postcow)
    id 5482521BF8E2; Wed,  7 Feb 2024 01:21:38 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Wed,  7 Feb 2024 01:21:38 +0000 (UTC)
From: MAILER-DAEMON@[REDACTED] (Mail Delivery System)
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
To: [REDACTED]
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="CA4EC21BFE80.1707268898/[REDACTED]"
Message-Id: <20240207012138.5482521BF8E2@[REDACTED]>

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.

--CA4EC21BFE80.1707268898/[REDACTED]
Content-Description: Notification
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

This is the mail system at host [REDACTED].

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<[REDACTED]>: connect to [REDACTED][[REDACTED]]:25:
    Connection timed out

--CA4EC21BFE80.1707268898/[REDACTED]
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; [REDACTED]
X-Postcow-Queue-ID: CA4EC21BFE80
X-Postcow-Sender: rfc822; [REDACTED]
Arrival-Date: Fri,  2 Feb 2024 01:10:13 +0000 (UTC)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; [REDACTED]
Original-Recipient: rfc822;[REDACTED]
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postcow; connect to [REDACTED]:25:
    Connection timed out

--CA4EC21BFE80.1707268898/[REDACTED]
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <[REDACTED]>
Received: from [[REDACTED]] (localhost [[REDACTED]]) by [REDACTED] (Mailerdaemon) with ESMTPSA id CA4EC21BFE80;
    Fri,  2 Feb 2024 01:10:13 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=[REDACTED];
    s=dkim; t=1706836214;
    h=from:subject:date:message-id:to:cc:mime-version:content-type;
    bh=[REDACTED]
    b=[REDACTED]
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2024 01:10:13 +0000
Message-ID: <BKAfB/m-40f2Z-AAAAAGINAACIBAAATe4OlSy5-[REDACTED]>
From: =?utf-8?Q?[REDACTED]?= <[REDACTED]>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Re:=[REDACTED]?=
To: =?utf-8?Q?[REDACTED]?= [REDACTED]
Cc: =?utf-8?Q?[REDACTED]?= [REDACTED]
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="=_9875f05c0d2ad638ed6e39eb808b5ce5"
X-Last-TLS-Session-Version: TLSv1.3

This is a message in Mime Format.  If you see this, your mail reader does not support this format.

--=_9875f05c0d2ad638ed6e39eb808b5ce5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
[REDACTED]
--=_9875f05c0d2ad638ed6e39eb808b5ce5--

--CA4EC21BFE80.1707268898/[REDACTED]--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  *Identification Fields* ([RFC 5322, 3.6.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.6.4)) `In-Reply-To` and `References` are designed for ordering email replies as threads. Bounces a.k.a. *Delivery Status Notifications* in [Postfix DSN Support](https://www.postfix.org/DSN_README.html) are based on [RFC 3464](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464.html) which does not mention these headers. It is a different concept from email replies, although [RFC 3834, 3.1.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834.html#section-3.1.6) would recommend using these headers in automatic replies including DSN. I am not aware of any configuration parameter that would alter this behaviour in Postfix.

As Postfix produces [RFC 3464](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464.html) based well formatted DSN messages it would be possible to add support for them in ticketing systems.

---

A closer look at osTicket's [`class Mail_Parse {}`](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/blob/9e45f3fa952c1b46f6acad5cca18b7baad6f0d6c/include/class.mailparse.php) reveals it supports RFC 3464 DSNs already:

1. If the `Content-Type` of any of the multi-part message's parts is `message/delivery-status`, the [`isBounceNotice()`](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/blob/9e45f3fa952c1b46f6acad5cca18b7baad6f0d6c/include/class.mailparse.php#L308) processes the **body** through `self::splitHeaders($body)` and looks for header `Action: failed`. The message is flagged as a bounce if it is found.
2. In such case [`parse($stream)`](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/blob/9e45f3fa952c1b46f6acad5cca18b7baad6f0d6c/include/class.mailparse.php#L779) gets the headers from [`getOriginalMessageHeaders()`](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/blob/9e45f3fa952c1b46f6acad5cca18b7baad6f0d6c/include/class.mailparse.php#L333), which gets the original headers from either `message/rfc822` or `text/rfc822-headers` message parts.  A DSN from Postfix has the original message and its headers in the former.

   - `references` comes from the original `References` header and
   - `in-reply-to` is taken either from `Message-ID` or `In-Reply-To` of the original message.

Comment: Thank you for the information, Could header re-writing not help here? I'll investigate the OSTicket solution but until then I'd accept header re-writing if possible.

Comment: Postfix's body checks cannot prepend headers, and the information you need is in the body. I think it would be easier to patch osTicket than use any indirect, potentially hacky approach.

Comment: I've updated my answer as a closer look at the osTicket's source code revealed that the support for RFC 3464 DSNs has already been implemented.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I'll see what I can do with it. I really appreciate it!

Comment: I have opened a PR which fixed the issue in osTicket. Your answer was pivotal to me finding the issue. You can read the pr here: https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/pull/6663

Thank you!